# Chnage Shape of Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-image

Hope everyone doing well. I am new in flutter I want to know how to give shape of an image like this, I have attached the sample... The image is coming from database

[image: Shape Image Like this]

Comment: Are you referring to the top right avatar ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stack widget,

```dart
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  children: [
    Positioned(
      top: -30, //negative value will shift to up side 
      right: -30, // this will shift pixel to the right
      child: Container(
          width: 100, //,
          height: 100,
          child: Image.network(
            " ",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: I am using a singleChildScrollView widget as well how i can use positioned widget with scroll?

Comment: Wrap `Stack` with SizedBox and provide height same as your top card. and then put the widget inside your SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 1):

Using Container and BoxDecoration along with clipBehaviour. Set the shape of Container to the shape you want, then set clipBehaviour to Clip.hardEdge

```
Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
  child: Image.asset('assets/default_avatar.png')),
```